# select2 how to get defaultvalue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the defaultSelected value from a select2 widget so that i can change its backgroundcolor.

It basically goes like this:

1. Serialize the form.
2. When an input (:text and dropdown) changes, compare new value to the defaultValue and toggle background-color.

The textboxes works but the dropdown wont.

A simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/228/) to illustrate the problem.

My question is **how do i get the select2 defaultValue so that it can be compared to the new value?** The background-color should only be toggled if the new value is `!==` the defaultValue and back to white if the defaultValue is reselected.

```
.text-changed {
    background-color: yellow!important;
}

$(".select2").on("change", function (e) {
    $(e.target).toggleClass("text-changed", e.target.value !== e.target.defaultSelected);
   // don't work with a select2
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should define your `default` value for `select`. 2nd: Select2 override your real select input. And you should work with new generated HTML.

**HTML**

```
<form>
   <select class="select2 my-options">
       <option default value="0">Default</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
       <option value="4">Option 4</option>
       <option value="5">Option 5</option>
   </select>
   <p>
       <input type="text" />
   </p>
   <p>
       <input type="text" />
   </p>
   <p>
       <input type="text" />
   </p>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(".select2").select2();

$("form")
   .each(function () {
   $(this).data("serialized", $(this).serialize());
}).on("change input", function (e) {   
   $(e.target).toggleClass("text-changed", e.target.value !== e.target.defaultValue);
}).on("change", "select", function (e) {       
   $('.my-options a').toggleClass("text-changed", e.target.value !== $(this).find("option[default]").attr("value"));   
});
```

See [this JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7mgwguzm/2/) example.

**EDITED**

And one more: I don't know exactly why, but in this case, you should use `background` not `background-color`.

**CSS**

```
.text-changed {
   background: yellow!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are what I changed:

```
<select class="select2">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option default value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>

$(".select2").change(function () {
    if ($(this).find(":selected").attr("value") == $(this).find("option[default]").attr("value")) {
        $(".select2-container").find("a").css("background", "yellow");
    } else {
        $(".select2-container").find("a").css("background", "");
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/229/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few changes to get this to work

### Correct your change handler for the text

First, the event handler for the input (text) is attached incorrectly. You need

```
.on("change", "input", function (e) {
    ...
```

The way it is now actually triggers it for the select change too.

---

### Update your select handler

You need to update your select change handler like below

```
.on("change", "select", function (e) {
      var selectedOption = $(e.target).children('option').filter(function() { return $(this).prop('defaultSelected') })
      var defaultValue = selectedOption[0] && selectedOption[0].value;
      $(e.target).toggleClass("text-changed", e.target.value != defaultValue);
});
```

This picks the default value from the option that is selected initially.

---

### Make your CSS more specific

You need to update your CSS to override the background image (simple overriding the background-color alone won't work) that chosen puts.

```
.text-changed a {
    background: yellow!important;
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9env2wpz/